# oauth2-proxy under Google Cloud Run unable to login with provider due querying DNS on IPV6

Tags: ipv6, google-cloud-run, oauth2-proxy

I'm implementing **oauth-proxy** ([Bitnami container](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/oauth2-proxy/)) for a backend service at my company under **Google Cloud Run**, with different settings and various providers (Azure/Microsoft Entra, and Google). When performing the login against Google provider, got this error:

```
error performing request: Post
"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token": dial tcp: lookup www.googleapis.com
on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:55482->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

Caused due the service is quering DNS on IPv6 I believe, getting connection refused (this also happens with Azure provider, where the container won't start at all due the same issue). It worked locally and at a normal Google Cloud Compute VM. As the container is unable to query Google API service through IPv4, I want to force the use of IPv4

I already tried to workarround that by forcing the IPv6 disable at the container level by adding `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but still having the same message.

I already set up the networking to use the VPC and enabling IPv6, but still not working.

Is there any further setting I can edit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your container is configured incorrectly. It is trying to connect on localhost `[::1]`. Your problem is not caused by any VPC settings or by IPv6.

Comment: John Hanley, as I mentioned, the issue happens only in Google Cloud Run. In a Google Cloud Compute VM (tested in COS and Ubuntu) and locally (using Docker Desktop) works fine.

Comment: That does not change my comment. Your container is not configured correctly. The application in your container is trying to connect to a DNS resolver at [::1] which is the IPv6 localhost. The connection is being refused because there is no DNS resolver listening on that address. I don't know the solution for the Bitnami container but it is not compatible with Cloud Run and based on your post, it is not compatible with Azure. Either dig into how the container is built or use a different one. AFAIK Cloud Run does not support IPv6 from the GFE to your application container.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community wiki based on @JohnHanley's comment:

> The container was configured incorrectly as it was trying to connect to localhost `[::1]` and it has nothing to do with VPC settings or IPv6.
>
> As of the moment, Cloud Run doesn't support IPv6 and you can configure your network through [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/overview). As of now this only supports IPv4. You may either use [VPC with connectors](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/vpc-connectors) or [shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-shared-vpc). Please be advised that IPv6 traffic is not supported as its [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#limitations).